# Ruby inject until sum exceeds a set value and return the index where this occurs

Tags: arrays, ruby, inject

With the following array and value:

```
v = 50
a = [10, 20, 25, 10, 15]
```

I want to iterate through the array adding up the values until the sum of these values exceeds the variable v. And then I want to be able to return the index in the array where that occurred. so...

10 + 20 + 25 = 55 (which is the first point which the sum is greater that 'v')
so index = 2

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sum:

```
a.inject do |sum,n|
  break sum if sum > v
  sum + n
end
```

For the index, idea is the same - you use the memo as an array and keep the sum in the first element:

```
a.inject([0,-1]) do |memo,n|
  break [memo[0], memo[1]] if memo[0] > v
  [memo[0]+n, memo[1]+1]
end
```

you need to look at the array after that

Comment: He's looking for the index at the point it passes, not the sum; which is what makes this tricky (inject doesn't pass index).

Comment: thanks, that returns sum that first exceeds v, is it possible to return the index of the array that this occurred at?

Comment: thanks, that works now.. didn't realise you could pass 'multiple memos' using an array!

Comment: @wawmsey: that is an important realization! Yes, `inject` reduces an `Enumerable` down to a single value, however, that single value can be as complex as you want it to be … for example, itself an `Enumerable` or an `Array` or a `Hash` or …

Answer (score 2):

A couple more ways

```
a.each_with_index.inject 0 do |acc, (n, idx)|
     break idx - 1 if acc > v
     acc + n
end
```

or

```
a.to_enum.with_index(-1).inject 0 do |acc, (n, idx)|
     next acc + n if acc < v
     break idx
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to `inject` over the indexes and access the outside array, since `inject` does not pass along the index; like so:

```
a.each_index.inject do |memo, i|
  break i if memo > v
  memo + a[i]
end
```