# Iterate over hash, and take values until some total sum limit is reached

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have two arrays of hashes that look something like this:

```
h1=[{id:1, item:1, value:10},
    {id:1, item:2, value:3}]

h2=[{id:1, item_a:1, value:5},{id:2, item_a:1, value:7},{id:3, item_a:1, value:10},
    {id:4, item_b:2, value:1},{id:5, item_b:2, value:2},{id:6, item_b:2, value:5},
    {id:7, item_b:2, value:1}]
```

I need to iterate through `h2` and:

1. for each `h1` hash, find an `h2` hash whose `item` corresponds to `item_a`, e.g., `item` value is `1` and `item_a` values is `1`,
2. take `value` from hash `h2` until sum of the items taken are equal to or bigger than the one in `h1` hash `value`,
3. create an array of arrays of ids from `h1` and `h2` whose first value is `id` from `h1` and second value is `id` from `h2`.

In my example above, the result would be `[[1,1],[1,2],[1,4],[1,5]]`.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903949/ruby-inject-until-sum-exceeds-a-set-value-and-return-the-index-where-this-occurs) here, however it just sums up the values up to some defined limit. I don't know how to take the values until some total sum is reached part. I hope someone can give me direction where I should be looking at.

**Update**

Result `[[1,1],[1,2],[1,4],[1,5]]` is because:

1. from `h1` we take first hash where `item:1` and `value:10`, so we need to collect ids from `h2` where `item_a:1` since I need `1` and `1` values (in real life - ids) and our total value should be at least `10`
2. we iterate through `h2` and start by first hash - its `value:5` which is smaller than `10` so we take it and we go to next hash - its `value:7` and if we sum it to previously taken `5`, we get `12` - it is bigger than `10` so **we take it and stop iteration** here as we are not allowed to take any more item. Our result for first iteration is: id from `h1` hash is `1` and ids from `h2` hash are `1` and `2`. So our array so far is `[[1,1],[1,2]]`
3. we do same thing for second hash from `h1`, where our matched **ids** from `h2` are `4` and `5`.

**Update 2**

I'm clearing out my example as there can be simply `item` in both hashes.
I'd like to expand a bit my example.

How would code change if extra criteria `from`-`to` date range and `date` criteria would be added in `h1` and `h2`?

```
h1=[{id:1, item:1, from: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,6,0,0,'+0300'), to: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,17,59,59,'+0300'), value:10},
   {id:1, item:2, from: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,18,0,0,'+0300'), to: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,23,59,59,'+0300'), value:10}]

h2=[{id:1, item:1, date: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,6,10,0,'+0300'), value:5},
    {id:2, item:1, date: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,7,20,0,'+0300'), value:7},
    {id:3, item:1, date: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,8,05,0,'+0300'), value:10},
    {id:4, item:2, date: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,18,19,10,'+0300'), value:1},
    {id:5, item:2, date: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,19,20,0,'+0300'), value:2},
    {id:6, item:2, date: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,22,22,0,'+0300'), value:5},
    {id:7, item:2, date: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,23,0,0,'+0300'), value:1}]
```

I'd like to take ids from only those hashes where `date` from `h2` is in range of `h1` dates in `from` - `to`. I assume I should put this `h2[:date].between?(h1[:from], h1[:to])` somewhere.

Comment: Can you explain a little further at how you arrive at the answer in your example? Steps. I can't quite follow.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Please, see my update above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off a couple assumptions I'm making, you don't mention `item_b` at all in your description, and only state that the link between `h1` and `h2` is the key `item_a`, so I'm assuming that `item_a` and `item_b` are equivalent...ie, you won't have something like `item_b: 1` that you wouldn't want to consider for the first hash in `h1` just because it's `item_b` and not `item_a`. If that's not correct, you'll need to adjust the code below accordingly (shouldn't be too difficult).

---

To start with, it will be easier if you group the items in `h2` by their `item_a/item_b` keys so you can just do a simple look up for them:

```
h2 = h2.group_by { |item| item[:item_a] || item[:item_b] }
# => {1=>[ {:id=>1, :item_a=>1, :value=>5},
           {:id=>2, :item_a=>1, :value=>7},
           {:id=>3, :item_a=>1, :value=>10} ],
      2=>[ {:id=>4, :item_b=>2, :value=>1},
           {:id=>5, :item_b=>2, :value=>2},
           {:id=>6, :item_b=>2, :value=>5},
           {:id=>7, :item_b=>2, :value=>1} ]
     }
```

Now, `h2[1]` has all the items that map to the first row of `h1` (based on the `item` key). Next, you want to map the values from `h1` into a list of array with the `id` from `h1` and the `id` from `h2` and the `id`s from `h2` come from a `take_while` loop, keeping track of a sum:

```
results = h1.map do |base|
  sum = 0

  h2[base[:item]].take_while do |item|
    sum += item[:value] if sum < base[:value]
  end.map do |item|
    [base[:id], item[:id]]
  end
end

# => [[[1, 1], [1, 2]], [[1, 4], [1, 5]]]
```

Lastly, you'll need to flatten by 1 level to get the result you want:

```
puts results.flatten(1).inspect
# => [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 5]]
```

Comment: Thank you. Basically idea is that value of `item` from `h1` and value of `item_a` from `h2` has to match. I added `item_b` just to somehow make it more clear of what I'm trying to accomplish. I will need some time to learn your code and test it on my exact case.

Comment: `(sum < base[:value]) && (sum += item[:value])` is a bit unorthodox why not simply `sum += item[:value] if sum < base[:value]`?

Comment: That works as well and is probably cleaner/clearer...this is what I get for coding before coffee. Updated

Comment: Your code works as expected, thank you. Would you mind having a look on my Update 2 above, where I've cleared out my example and extended my question a bit, please?

Comment: @matiss that is now a new question please don't change the question after accepting an answer as it can orphan an accepted answer and others because you have changed the criteria

Answer (score 1):

I too have questions about the keys `:item_a` and `:item_b` (and presumably `:item_c`, etc.) in `h2`. One could assume `:item_a` pertains to `h1[0]`,  `:item_b` to `h1[1]`, and so on, but it's easier to just give them all the same name, which I've chosen to be `:item`. That is, having `item_a` and `item_b` does not make it a more difficult problem, it just introduces a nuisance from a coding standpoint.

```
h1 = [{ id:1, item:1, value:10 }, { id:1, item:2, value:3 }]
h2 = [{ id:1, item:1, value:5 },  { id:2, item:1, value:7 }, { id:3, item:1, value:10 },
      { id:4, item:2, value:1 },  { id:5, item:2, value:2 }, { id:6, item:2, value:5},
      { id:7, item:2, value:1 }]
```

I have assumed that, for each hash `g` in `h1`, if `g[:value]` is greater than the sum of `f[:value]` over all hashes `f` in `h2` for which `f[:item] = g[:item]`, `[g[:id], f[:id]`, for all such hashes `f`, would be included in the array that is returned. (Whew!) If, instead, `g` should simply be disregarded is the sum of values from `h2` insufficient, that requires only a small change to the code below.

The first step is to construct another hash from `h2`.

```
h = h2.each_with_object({}) do |g, h|
  h.update(g[:item]=>[[g[:id], g[:value]]]) do |_, o, n|
    o << [g[:id], o.last.last + g[:value]]
  end
end
  #=> {1=>[[1, 5], [2, 12], [3, 22]], 2=>[[4, 1], [5, 3], [6, 8], [7, 9]]}
```

As you see, `h` has keys equal to the values of `:item` and values that are arrays of pairs of `:id` values and "cumulative" values of `:value`.

```
h1.each_with_object([]) do |g, a|
  id1 = g[:id]
  value1 = g[:value]
  arr = h[g[:item]]
  i = arr.index { |_id2, cum| value1 <= cum } || (arr.size - 1)
  arr[0..i].map(&:first).each { |id2| a << [id1, id2] }
end
  #=> [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 5]]
```

The steps following the calculation of `h` are as follows.

```
a = []
g = { id:1, item:1, value:10 }
id1 = g[:id]
  #=> 1
value1 = g[:value]
  #=> 10
arr = h[g[:item]]
  #=> h[1]
  #=> [[1, 5], [2, 12], [3, 22]]
i = arr.index { |_id2, cum| value1 <= cum } || (arr.size - 1)
  #=> 1
```

If `value1` had been, say `100`, we would obtain `arr.index { |_id2, cum| value1 <= cum } #=> nil`. In this case `i` is set equal to the "or'ed" term `arr.size - 1`.

```
b = arr[0..i]
  #=> [[1, 5], [2, 12]]
c = b.map(&:first)
  #=> [1, 2]
c.each { |id2| a << [id1, id2] }
a #=> [[1, 1], [1, 2]]
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

Comment: Thank you. It seems a bit more rows than in Simple Lime answer above. Do you see there would be some performance advantages of your code in case I have several thousands of hashes? In addition, could you take a look  on my Update 2 above, where I've cleared and expanded my example a bit, please?